# ViewWillAppear cannot be called when coming from swift background to foreground

Tags: swift

I am making a timer

The timer doesn't work in the background

I am trying to calculate the time when I go to the background to store data and return to the foreground.

Using the `sceneDidEnterBackground` and `sceneWillEnterForeground` events of `AppDelegate(SceneDelegate)`

I'm receiving events when going to the background and coming to the foreground.

The problem is that we need to calculate the background time and display it in the actual view.

When an existing view is opened, `viewWillAppear` cannot be called

How do I update the existing view?

The view is a tab bar view

Comment: Use "NotificationCentre.default.observer" method to update the timer as well as View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Declare variable to calculated time-interval of inactive to the active state**

```
 fileprivate var appTimeWhenGoesToInactive:Date = Date()
 fileprivate var dismissInterval = 0
```

**Add Notification observer code in the "viewDidLoad" method to observe the changes**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(saveCurrentTimeToObserve), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(matchCurrentTimeForNewPosts), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

}
```

**Add their selector method to perform the UI update as well as interval calculation of active to inactive state transformation:-**

```
 @objc fileprivate func saveCurrentTimeToObserve(){

   appTimeWhenGoesToInactive = Date()
 }

 @objc fileprivate func matchCurrentTimeForNewPosts(){
        
  dismissInterval =   dismissInterval - 
 appTimeWhenGoesToInactive.timeIntervalSinceNow //------- Here time-interval Comes. Add below, your UI updation code according to time-interval value.
          
                  
              
    }
 }
```